# I want to create rdd by accessing csv file in spark using a python 2 cluster

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I have a csv file that I imported to databricks. I created a cluster and a notebook to create RDD for the file, I tried multiple codes but couldn't access the file.

I have tried a lot of codes but all of them gave me errors except one. the one that didn't give me error didn't show me any result and I want to be able to display the results too.

Here is the one that gave an error:

```
# Create RDD to access dept
dept = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/dept.csv")
dept.take(3)
```

Here is the one that didn't give an error:

```
# Create RDD to access dept
import csv/
rdd = sc.textFile("dept.csv")
rdd = rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: csv.reader(x))
```

I expect that actual result with be a table of three columns

Comment: Can you include the error message in your question?

Comment: this is the error i get for the first code org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: /FileStore/tables/dept.csv

Comment: I removed dept.take(3) and I think the program is able to read the data but I am able to view it.